# ¿Como obtener el width de la pantalla dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para obtener el `width` mediante jquery se que es asi:

```
$(window).width();
```

Pero esto me da unicamente el valor de la pantalla actual, si cambio la resolucion tengo que refrescar la web para obtener el nuevo valor. Como hago para obtener el `width` de la pantalla dinamicamente, que lo muestre mientras va cambiando la resolucion de la web. Por ejemplo:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Esta me muestra el posicionamiento del scroll vertical dinamicamente, quisiera lo mismo pero con el `width` de la pantalla, ¿Como se consigue?

Comment: usa la funcion `resize()` y ahi llamas el `$(window).width();`

Comment: Y por qué no meter esa funcionalidad en un setInterval que cada segundo se vaya actualizando el valor devuelto ?

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila No se me había ocurrido usar esa función hermano, aplicándola obtengo el resultado deseado. Gracias

Comment: Con gusto, es muy util

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila Agrega tu comentario como una respuesta para que quede registro y de paso obtengas puntuación. Digo, si así lo deseas!

Comment: ok, gracias @DjCrazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con la función `resize()` de [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) lo puedes lograr

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(window).width();
});
```